# Using Local storage data in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension where i have an input field and 2 buttons in the popup. 
when the user clicks on it first time the 1st button is active and 2nd is disabled.

Once the user inputs a value and clicks on the button 1, button 1 becomes disabled, button 2 becomes active and the value of button 1 changes from lock val to the text user inputted. I am storing the value inputted in local storage.

The next time the user clicks on the extension, i want the button 2 to be active and button 1 to be disabled.

I am doing a storage get at doc ready but this doesn't seem to be solving this.

popup.html

```
<body>
    <label for="sel1">Enter Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Id1" placeholder="Enter Name">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id ='btn1'> LOCK Name </button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" id='btn2'> Add in CRM </button>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
```

popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    chrome.storage.local.get('id',function(res1){
      var IdFound = res1;
      if(!IdFound) {
        $('#btn2').prop('disabled',true);
      } else {
        $('#btn2').prop('disabled',false)
      }

      });

    $('#btn1').on('click',function() {
          var id1 = 'id';
          var id2 = $('#Id1').val();
          chrome.storage.local.set({id1:id2});
          $('#btn1').prop('disabled',true).html(id2);
          $('#btn2').prop('disabled',false);   
      });


    $('#btn2').on('click',function(){
          chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {id3: "true"}, function(response) {
              console.log(response.farewell);
            });
          })
      });


});
```

Comment: It looks like you're setting `id` but getting `mid`.

Comment: @ChrisG - sorry that's a typo while adding code here.

Comment: Please click the `<>` and add HTML and jQuery to make a [mcve]

Comment: What do you think `{id1:id2}` creates? Did you mean `{[id1]:id2}`?